# sed add first word from previous line to beginning of the next line, if

Tags: awk, sed, regular-expression, text-formatting, replace

I ran into a problem and can't find a solution to fix the following issue.

I want to copy the first word of a line to the beginning of the following n lines if they start with a special character, else copy the new word.

Input:

```
aaa random words

`dsf

|df

bbb

|d
```

Output:

```
aaa random words

aaa`dsf

aaa|df

bbb

bbb|d
```

Comment: You've mentioned `sed` in the title and tags.  Is it required to use `sed` for the solution, or are other tools (such as `awk`) OK?

Comment: awk is also ok, I just never used it

Comment: Welcome! You have aaa and then bbb as substitution. How do you decide wich string to replace? Or it's the ones that are not followed by a special char? Or it's a typo?

Comment: In this case I can limit it to: **|** and **`**

Comment: In the second line of your desired output example, you had a space between `aaa` and the backtick, although the input line seemed to start without space. Was that a typo, or do you want space-separation between the copied word and the line content in some cases?

Comment: Typo. I use sed to remove all spaces first, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An awk oneliner:

```
awk '/^[[:alnum:]]/ {prefix = $1; print; next} {print prefix $0}' input
```

- On lines starting with an alphanumeric character, store the first word in `prefix`, print the line and continue to the next line.
- On all other lines print `prefix` before the line.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -f 1stword.awk < input
```

Where `1stword.awk` contains the following script:

```
$0 ~ /^[[:alnum:]]/ { word=$1 ; print }   # save 1st word
$0 ~ /^[^[:alnum:]]/ { print word$0 }     # prepend saved word
```

The `[:alnum:]` in the character range means all alphanumeric characters.  Adjust to a different character range according to your definition of "special characters".

Comment: Ty for answering, I will try to get it working for me